# how to save regression result in R

Tags: r

I am new to R studio. I wonder how to save the regression result. For example, I am using the support vector regression to do analysis, it always took couple hours for one model, I don't want to just save "R code", but also every variable, dataset, regression result. 
Thank you!

Comment: `?save` ........

Comment: or `save.image`, if you want the whole workspace

Comment: save.image? Is it just save the graph? But what I want is, for instance, a file that can save every current data, which we don't need to import again, or the regression result so that we don't need to do "svm()" again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save.image(file="mysession.RData")` will save all of the objects in your current workspace to a file (which can be read back into R via `load("mysession.RData")`). It may be better to use `save()` or `saveRDS()` to save the particular object(s) you're interested in, and leave out any temporary junk you've created during your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the save.model function in the maxent package:

```
install.packages("maxent")
library(maxent)

x <- seq(1,10,1)
y <- rnorm(10)
fit <- lm(y ~ x)

> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0170 -0.3886  0.1401  0.5988  0.8532 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -1.1555     0.6297  -1.835   0.1038  
x             0.2665     0.1015   2.626   0.0304 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9218 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.463, Adjusted R-squared:  0.3959 
F-statistic: 6.897 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.03035
```

You can save your full regression model like this:

```
> save.model(fit,"myfit")
```

Then you can load the model up again later:

```
> newfit <- load.model("myfit")
> summary(newfit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0170 -0.3886  0.1401  0.5988  0.8532 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -1.1555     0.6297  -1.835   0.1038  
x             0.2665     0.1015   2.626   0.0304 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9218 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.463, Adjusted R-squared:  0.3959 
F-statistic: 6.897 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.03035
```